# How do you build TextMate on windows?

Tags: windows, textmate

I know that TextMate is not for windows but it is opensource so can you build it on windows and run it correctly?

Comment: Code written specifically for Mac will not compile on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Code written specifically for Mac will not compile on Windows. Thanks @selbie for the words. Couldn’t have said it better myself.